# onclick event for marker is not working in openlayer3 on changing the size of the div

Tags: resize, click, openlayers-3, markers

i am plotting the markers on the map in openlayer3 as shown below

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rotation example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/build/ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:1000px"></div>
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions:  ({
                    collapsible: false,
                })
            }),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.986908, 1.353199]),
                rotation: 68*Math.PI/180,
                zoom: 18
            })
        });
    }
    function invokeAddMarker(){
        var markerData = [
            {
                "title": 'point1',
                "lat": 1.350664,
                "lng": 103.985190,
                "description": 'yyyy'
            }, {
                "title": 'point2',
                "lat":1.353604,
                "lng": 103.986395,
                "description": 'zzz'
            }, {
                "title": 'point3',
                "lat": 1.357227,
                "lng": 103.9879999,
                "description": 'uuu'
            }
        ];
        for(var i=0;i<markerData.length;i++){
             addmarker(markerData[i].lat,markerData[i].lng);
        }
    }
    function addmarker(lat,lng){
        console.log("*****lat******"+lat);
        console.log("*****lng******"+lng);
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lng,lat],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
            name: 'camera'
        });
        var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor: [0.5, 46],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                opacity: 0.75,
                src: 'camera.png'
            }))
        });
        iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
        vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [iconFeature]
        });
        /*t clear the markers*/
        /*vectorSource.clear();*/
        vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource
        });
        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
        map.on('click', function(evt) {
            var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
                    function(feature, layer) {
                        return feature;
                    });
            if (feature) {
                alert("video comes here");

            }

        });
    }
    initMap();
    invokeAddMarker();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am facing two problem in the above code 
1:the click event will fired 3 times ie, the number marker on the map that should only onces by theory
2:when i resize the div say(new width and height of the div is varied to new value in which the map is displayed)the markers will adjust to div but the event is not fired

please say why is this behavior and how to overcome it

Comment: You didn't show the `resize` relevant code but the first problem is easy: you're registering `click` event inside the `for` loop.

Comment: thanks i am not sure of how to define the click event outside that method which is invoke using for loop can u please change the code and post the answer

Comment: Please read carefully my first comment!

Comment: thanks i am not sure of how to define the click event outside that method which is invoke using for loop can u please change the code and post the answer